# Rendering the page in django with html form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have these two functions, one of them (first one) adds a new entry and the second one edits the entry:

```
def add_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            if util.get_entry(title) is None:
                util.save_entry(title, content)
                return redirect('entry', title)
            else:
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/add_entry.html", {
                    "form": AddForm(),
                    "title": title
                })

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/add_entry.html", {
        "form": AddForm()
    })


def edit_entry(request, title):
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('entry', title)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry.html", {
        "title": title,
        "content": content
```

Here is my edit_entry.html page:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'edit_entry' title %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <input type="text" value="{{ title }}">
    <h5>Content</h5>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10">{{ content }}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Editing">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is add_entry.html template

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Add new entry
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Create a new page</h1>
    {% if title %}
        <h6 style="color: red;">"{{title}}" page is already exists. Please, enter a different title</h6>
    {% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'add_entry' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my urls.py:
from django.urls import path

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_entry", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>/edit_entry", views.edit_entry, name="edit_entry")
]
```

My entry view:

```
def entry(request, title):
    if title not in util.list_entries():
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "error": "Page Not Found",
            "query": title
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)),
            "title": title
        })
```

The issue here when I click to save the content of the page doesn't change, I want to save the edits and display it with new content. Instead, it returns an old form with the old content (like doesn't change).

Comment: how does your ```entry``` view look like? also add ```else: print(form.errors)``` so you can access the error message

Comment: @ha-neul Edited, added this also

Comment: Where to add? In enrty function?

Comment: difficult to explain in comment, so I put it in the answer. it will help you to see form error message in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: based on your comments, I think it is better to start over**.
Since you are doing some simple create and update, it maybe better to use **generic views**. Here is an example.

**1.First and formost, you need a model.**

in models.py,

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
```

**2. in your forms.py**
Note: this is not necessary if you want to just use django default form. Because class-based generic views will automatically generate forms for you. However, if you need to add widget, or to add attributes (for example, add css class or id), you need to generate a customform.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Entry

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('title', 'content')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title'}),
            'content': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'content'}),
        }
```

**3. views.py**

```
from .models import Entry
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView

class CreateEntry(CreateView):
    model=Entry
    template_name = 'create_edit_entry.html' # this is the template, you might need to change its path.

    form_class= EntryForm # this is added because we are using customform

    success_url = '/' #this can be changed

class UpdateEntry(UpdateView):
    model=Entry
    template_name = 'create_edit_entry.html'

    form_class= EntryForm
```

**4. urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CreateEntry, UpdateEntry

urlpatterns = [
    path('entry/', CreateEntry.as_view(), name='create_entry'),
    path('entry/<int:pk>', UpdateEntry.as_view(), name='update_entry'),

]
```

**5. admins.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Entry

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (('id', 'title', 'content'))

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

**6. templates (create_edit_entry.html)**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block extrahead %} 
{% load static %}
  
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After you update all these files and update mysite/urls.py, you will 1) open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/entry` to add an entry. Check if the entry is created in your admin page. 2) then you will open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/entry/1` (if the id=1) to see if your original entry is shown. 3) then you will update the form, and check if the update is successful or not in your admin.

This backbone should be able to get you started. Note that I did not put DetailView, ListView, so you need to check if the object is created and updated in your admin page. Of cause, you can add DetailView and ListView by yourself ([check out django document here to learn more about generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)).

**************************************earlier answer **************

**1.** First thing first, it is always helpful to access form.errors when you are having trouble with forms. What you do is to add  `else: print(form.errors)` like the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
     # other code

else:
     print(form.errors)
```

**2.**
Your `edit_entry.html` change to something like below: I guess you wanted use your own styling (add Title, Content etc) to the form, so you did not use {{form}}. If what I suggest worked, you can add form styling later.

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'edit_entry' title %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**3.** your `edit_entry` view:

```
def edit_entry(request, title):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, title=title) # i assume your Model name is "Entry"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST, instance = entry)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('under form.is_valid) # add this line to keep track
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            form.save()
            return redirect('entry', title=entry.title)
         else:
             print(form.errors)

    else:
        form = AddForm(instance = entry)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry.html", {
        'form': form})
```

Comment: Added it, thanks. But I can't find any solution via it yet.

Comment: Is there an error message in the terminal? looks like you are directly going to the render.

Comment: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>title<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>content<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` @ha-neul, This kind of error in the terminal is displaying

Comment: 1. Good advice, thanks. 
2. I wanted display without using django forms, just wanted the "title" be in `<input>` tag and the content in `<textarea>` tag. But for the `add_entry` function I've used django forms. It means that django form and HTML form will not work here? 
3. I am not using any model here. So, what should I put instead of 'Entry'? And why you redirecting like `return redirect('entry', title=entry.title)`, in my case `return redirect('entry', title)` would work fine?

Comment: Hi I updated my answer with a full working example using generic views. Please check it out.

Comment: Hello. There are many unfamiliar things for me. I am learning Django on a special online course. Would you suggest me read the django docs for better understanding your version? 
Do you suggest I read the django docs for a better understanding of your version? Or do you recommend just trying it?  Actually, I found the solution to my problem with forms, using `initial` value of the forms (if you are aware of this function). But this method was a bit strange for me for understanding. So I decided to do it with html forms. I just wanted to combine my django form with HTML.

Comment: Glad that you are learing Django, it is a fun program to learn. It's up to you. In the later part of your online course, you will learn about class-based views (especially these useful generic views). You can come back to my answer then.

Comment: Ok, I will review your method then. It was useful information for me. Thank you.